# Re-add a UIButton

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, ipad, uibutton

I'm creating a simple matching game for kids for iPad. All images are drawn on buttons.

When a matching pair is found,
`[matchedBtn1 removeFromSuperview];`1
`[matchedBtn2 removeFromSuperview];`

Now, I'm creating a reset function which allows player to reset the once he/she is done.
Question is how do I re-add the `UIButtons</code>?`

Tried this,
`[self addSubview:matchBtn1];`

But the program crashes once reset button is clicked and gives this warning for every button I `addSubview` to
**"viewController" *may not respond to* "-addSubview".**

Many thanks in advance for your help. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should be trying to add them to the view of the controller, not the view controller itself.

```
[[viewController view] addSubView:matchBtn1];
```

Also make sure you have kept a retained copy of matchBtn1 somewhere in your classes as it will have been released when you removed the subviews.

Answer (score 3):

try :

```
[self.view addSubview:matchBtn1];
```

Comment: oo the code I was looking for... no wonder, I forgot .view. thanks! =)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of adding and removing them, create a set of transparent views over the buttons and when you want to remove them, change the color of those views so that the buttons are hidden. That way if you want to reset the screen, you just have to reset all those views to transparent. You may have to set the cover views to intercept touches too, so the user doesn't click hidden buttons.